# How to pass object to angularjs controller using MVC controller Action

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I want to send object to angularjs Controller using MVC Controller Action is it possible?

suppose

```
 public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I want to pass object to app.js how to do this

Comment: Be more specific.  Also post the code.

Comment: By `MVC Controller Action` you mean from `Spring` controller?

Comment: no from Asp.net MVC controller action means in return view() i want to pass data to angularjs controller i want know is it possible or not

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague , you need to be more specific on what exactly you are trying to do.

Generally , this his how you would get data in Angular from the MVC application.

In Case of MVC/WebAPI , you should use actions to return JSON  result back to the angular service which can then be processed by angular.
Example below :

```
  app.factory('myService', function($http) {
  var myService = {
    GetData: function() {
      // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
      var promise = $http.get('<ActionURL>').then(function (response) {
        // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
        console.log(response);
        // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
        return response.data;
      });
      // Return the promise to the controller
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return myService;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function( myService,$scope) {
  // Call the async method and then do stuff with what is returned inside our own then function
  myService.GetData().then(function(d) {
    $scope.data = d;
  });
});
```

After this services is called from the MainCtrl , angular will have the data from the MVC action available in its $scope.data variable.

Comment: This is the preferred approach. It's also possible to deserialize a model to json which saves a trip to the server

Comment: @JeffDunlop : How do you mean ? Cant visualize what you mean from the comment . Got a sample ?